# Prove a Set of Functions is Closed By proving the complement is open?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'd like to prove that the set of continuous functions on [0,1] with the sup norm satisfying
$$\int_0^{.5} f(t)dt - \int_{.5}^{1} f(t)dt = c$$
for some constant $c$ is closed.

I think most proofs would involve showing the set contains all of its limit points. But, it seems easier to show the complement is open.

Proof:
Start with $f$ not in the set described above. We consider the case where

$$\int_0^{.5} f(t)dt - \int_{.5}^{1} f(t)dt > c$$
Then consider the set of functions $B(f,\epsilon)$ where $||f-h||_{\infty}<\epsilon$ for any $h\in B(f,\epsilon)$.

Then we can construct some continuous $g\in B(f,\epsilon)$.

Let $g$ be defined as follows.

$g(t)=f(t)$ for $t\in(.5,1]$ and let $g(t)= f(t)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}(.5-x)$ for $t\in [0,.5]$.

Each piece is continuous on its respective portion of the domain and $f(.5)=g(.5)$, so $g$ is continuous on all of $[0,1]$ as $\lim_{x\rightarrow .5} g(x) = g(.5)$ from any direction.

Furthermore, $g\geq f$ and $||f-g||_\infty = \epsilon /2$.  The former implies that $$\int_0^{.5} g(t)dt - \int_{.5}^{1} g(t)dt > c.$$
The remaining case follows similarly. Hence, the complement of the original set is open. Therefore, the set is closed.

Is there any reason this doesn't work or should be proven differently?

Comment: IMO proving it has all it's limit points is pretty straightforward: Since this is a metric space it's first countable so we can characterize a limit point as the limit of some sequence in $C([0,1])$ so now let $\{g_n\}$ be a sequence of functions in the space that converge then uniform convergence of $g_n$ allows us to say the limit is continuous and that we can swap the limit and the integral so that the limit is in the space as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems correct. In my opinion the simplest way to prove continuity in this case is to show that the map $T\colon C[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
Tf=\int_0^{1/2}f(t)\,dt-\int_{1/2}^0f(t)\,dt
$$
is continuous. Then for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$ the set $T^{-1}(\{c\})$ is closed.